# How to customise the default language sitemap url in a multilanguage Hugo website

Tags: sitemap, hugo

I have a multilanguage website in Hugo and right now the sitemap generated automatically is the following:

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <sitemap>
   <loc>https://domain/en/sitemap.xml</loc>
   <lastmod>2022-04-20T08:34:57+02:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
   <loc>https://domain/it/sitemap.xml</loc>
   <lastmod>2022-04-20T08:34:57+02:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

The issue is that all the content in English, which is the default language, does not contain /en in the url but simply the slug itself, such as /products /blog. The italian content contains the language indication in the url instead, such as /it/prodotti, /it/blog.

Sitemap-wise, it doesn't seem to be advisable to have the english sitemap in /en/sitemap. It should be in /domain/sitemap_en.xml instead.

Any clue on how to customise the localised url of the sitemap?

Thank you.

Comment: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/sitemap-at-root-level-on-a-multi-language-website/29969
https://gohugo.io/content-management/multilingual/
I think what's outputting above is correct. However, the above links should help you if you want to "roll your own"

Comment: I do not see why this would be benificial.

Comment: Here's why: https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location

Comment: To avoid a cross submission error, you can use robots.txt as described in https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#sitemaps_cross_submits

In any case, I've only seen the host restriction followed, I have yet to see a service implementing /path/ restriction.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the hugo Built-in Template for sitemapindex:
https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/tpl/tplimpl/embedded/templates/_default/sitemapindex.xml

They use `.SitemapAbsURL` variable, but I didn't find in documentation from where it came. However, you could rewrite sitemapindex for example with `.Permalik`

> To override the built-in sitemapindex.xml template, create a new file in either of these locations:
>
> - layouts/sitemapindex.xml
> - layouts/_default/sitemapindex.xml

Comment: Thank you Halyna, the issue is that I would't want to redirect / to /en/. I would just like to have the sitemap reflect the real url path and not add /en/.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the off-topic answer. I tried to do some research and modified my answer. Hope it could help you.